# WTForms and Flask - Validate file size in another field

Tags: validation, flask, wtforms

I have a structure like this in my Flask app:

```
class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
        username = StringField('Username',
                       validators=[DataRequired(),
                                   Length(min=2, max=20)])
        email = StringField('Email address',
                    validators=[DataRequired(),
                                Email()])
        domain_name = StringField('Project name',
                          validators=[DataRequired()])
        dir_level = IntegerField(
            'Folder level', validators=[DataRequired()])
        file = FileField('Upload textfile', validators=[
                         FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['txt'])])
        scan_now = BooleanField('Scan website now')
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

The **scan_now** field submits the project into a different, faster queue and it is used for priority reports.

Given that **scan_now** is more computationally expensive, I would like to limit its usage only for .txt files that have less than 500 rows, and raise error if a user checks the box but has uploaded more than 500 rows.

How can I do that?

Thanks you!

EDIT:

Since you have requested my manager views file, here's the logic behind it:

```
@manager.route("/manage_url", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@auth.login_required
def manage_url():
    form = UploadForm()
    config = []
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        date = datetime.today()
        date = date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        file = request.files['file']
        filename = file.filename
        email = request.form['email']
        username = request.form['username']
        livello_dir = request.form['livello_dir']
        domain_name = request.form['domain_name']
        try:
            scan_now = request.form['scan_now']
        except:
            scan_now = False
        file.save(os.path.join(uploads_dir, secure_filename(filename)))
        # crea file config da leggere
        config_entry = {
            filename:
            {
                "date": date,
                "email": email,
                "user": username,
                "domain_name": domain_name.replace(" ", "_"),
                "livello_dir": livello_dir
            }
        }
        config.append(config_entry)
        if not os.path.exists('./config.json'):
            with open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'config.json'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump(config, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        else:
            with open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'config.json'), 'r') as f:
                config = json.load(f)
            config.append(config_entry)
            with open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'config.json'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump(config, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        if scan_now:
            def on_the_fly_scan():
                executor = Executor()
                executor.start_process(file=filename)
            thread = Thread(target=on_the_fly_scan)
            thread.daemon = True
            thread.start()
        return redirect(url_for('manager.manage_url'))

    try:
        files = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads'))
        paths = [os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads') +
                 "/" + file for file in files]
    except:
        files = None
        paths = None

    domini = []
    contact = ""
    operator_name = ""
    livello_dir = ""

    for file in paths:
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='unicode_escape') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
            rows = list(csv_reader)

            dominio_rilevato = tldextract.extract(rows[1][0]).registered_domain
            domini.append(dominio_rilevato)

    with open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'config.json'), 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    content_package = list(zip(domini, files))

    return render_template("manage_url.html",
                           content_package=content_package,
                           data=data,
                           config_entries=list(list(d.keys()) for d in data),
                           form=form,
                           contact=contact,
                           operator_name=operator_name,
                           livello_dir=livello_dir)
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question and post that part of logic of route as well where you are collecting all these values. Will be more explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Validate file size manually before saving the file. add these lines before `file.save(os.path.join(uploads_dir, secure_filename(filename)))` :

```py
if scan_now:
    if count_rows(filename) > 500:
        raise Exception('too many rows')
        # or whatever you need to do
```

And here's the `count_rows()` code :

```py
def count_rows(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return sum(1 for row in f)
        # if file is in csv format return sum() - 1
        # because first line is not a record
        return sum(1 for row in f) - 1
```